# what is the alternate tag/directive for ng-cloak of angularjs in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

For a project, I am degrading AngularJS to jQuery/JavaScript. I see this particular tag "ng-cloak". Is there any alternate way for re-writing ng-cloak in jQuery or JavaScript. Haven't found anything yet, could someone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Angular templates are just normal elements, with some extra attributes, that are transformed using JavaScript. This transformation takes some time, and in the meantime the raw, untransformed template elements could be shown to the user. `ng-cloak` hides the template until it is processed by Angular.

If you do not have templates in visible HTML elements, there is no reason for the `ng-cloak` mechanism. If you are writing in plain JavaScript, you can choose to not use templates at all, or to put them into `<script>` or `<template>` elements, or to load them dynamically from a server... none of which would be visible to the user.

If you do have something you want to temporarily hide, the mechanism of `ng-cloak` is described pretty well in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> `ngCloak` works in cooperation with the following css rule embedded within `angular.js` and `angular.min.js`. For CSP mode please add `angular-csp.css` to your html file (see ngCsp).
>
> ```
> [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
>   display: none !important;
> }
> ```
>
> When this css rule is loaded by the browser, all html elements (including their children) that are tagged with the `ngCloak` directive are hidden. When AngularJS encounters this directive during the compilation of the template it deletes the `ngCloak` element attribute, making the compiled element visible.

Comment: I have a custom tag like this <c-app cid="TEST" ng-cloak=""></c-app> 
and in the script section :
switch statement:
case  "TEST" :
do something
break;

So I want to know if I can do something about ng-cloak to replace it, not to hide it